# ExtJS Grid cell editor, prevent focus loose issue

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem with grid cell editor. I have the validation for cells, and I need to prevent them from loosing focus in case when validation error happens. That's how I'm doing it:

```
blur: function (field, event) {
                            if (field.value > field.maxValue || field.value < field.minValue) {
                                field.focus();
                                return false;
                            }
                        },
specialkey: function (field, event) {
                            if (event.getKey() == 9 ) {
                                if (field.value > field.maxValue || field.value < field.minValue) {
                                    field.focus();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

This part works ok for cases when you try to click anywhere outside the grid, or try to select next cell using Tab. The problem is that if you'll click another cell, I'll still loose focus. That's what debug showed:

```
cell_1 - blur, cell_1 - focus, cell_2 - blur, cell_2 - focus
```

Does anybody got similar problem?

Also a bit confusing that if you'll place breakpoint in to the "blur" listener, it will work! Debug will show: cell_1 - blur and no other events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do your validation in the `beforeedit` event of the `cellediting` plugin (at least in ExtJs 4) :

```
this.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
        clicksToEdit : 1,
        listeners : {
            beforeedit : function (editor, e) {
                // do your valdiation here :
                return (e.record.get('your_field') != 'aaa');
            }
        }
    });
```

If you return false here it will cancel the edition.